# Gammu: RunOnReceive script returns "Process failed with exit status 1"

Tags: bash, raspbian, gammu

I'm trying to make my raspberry working sending and receiving sms.
Send works fine. I'm not able to handle the receive message.
I followed all guides I found on the web but still something wrong.

This is the gammu.log:

```
Thu 2017/06/22 00:40:30 gammu-smsd[668]: Received message from: MYNUMBER
Thu 2017/06/22 00:40:30 gammu-smsd[668]: Read 1 messages
Thu 2017/06/22 00:40:30 gammu-smsd[668]: Received IN20170622_004025_00_MYNUMBER_00.txt
Thu 2017/06/22 00:40:30 gammu-smsd[6813]: Starting run on receive: sudo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/smsReceived.sh IN20170622_004025_00_MYNUMBER_00.txt 
Thu 2017/06/22 00:40:30 gammu-smsd[668]: Process failed with exit status 1
```

So, the sms is received and triggered by gammu-smsd but the script fails.
It means that the script is not really executed.
The script itself is a call of cgi:

```
#!/bin/bash
wget "http://192.168.1.110/cgi-bin/myscript.cgi"
exit 0
```

But I tried also with

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "hello!"
exit 0
```

I set rights to the script at max: 777

If I call the script manually, it works perfeclty!
I feel I'm facing a problem of rights but I'm not able to find the reason.

This is my configuration:

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
# Please configure this!
port = /dev/ttyUSB0
connection = at19200
# Debugging
#logformat = textall

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
RunOnReceive = sudo /usr/lib/cgi-bin/myscript.sh   
service = files
logfile = /var/log/gammu.log
```

Any idea?

Comment: Hi, same issue here tried various options with chmod also tried editing the etc/init.d/gammu-smsdrc but no results. i think its somewhere in the options the script has according to gammu